# Akamai CCU V3 Fast Purge implementation with JAVA project or AEM

Tags: java, aem, akamai

Has anyone tried integrating there java code from CCU V2 to CCU V3 with fast purge. I read the documentation but unable to understand what needs to be done in case of a java based project. After we have configured the client in Akamai console how do we write the code to access and clear.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tushar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Shawn has answered is mostly correct. Though you would like to have more things in plate like your custom replication agent, a custom content builder and a transport handler if you are integrating it with AEM. Also, there can be few dependency issues as well.
If you need help with all these, you can refer to below article:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/akamai-cache-purge-aem-through-java-code-shubham-saxena/

For a transport handler you can use below snippet:

```
    package com.myproject.bundle.core.services.impl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.util.Base64;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONArray;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONException;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.sling.commons.osgi.PropertiesUtil;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.akamai.edgegrid.signer.ClientCredential;
import com.akamai.edgegrid.signer.exceptions.RequestSigningException;
import com.akamai.edgegrid.signer.googlehttpclient.GoogleHttpClientEdgeGridRequestSigner;
import com.day.cq.replication.AgentConfig;
import com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationActionType;
import com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationException;
import com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationResult;
import com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationTransaction;
import com.day.cq.replication.TransportContext;
import com.day.cq.replication.TransportHandler;
import com.myproject.bundle.core.configuration.BaseConfigurationService;
import com.myproject.bundle.core.constants.MyConstants;
import com.myproject.bundle.core.search.services.MyProjectConfigurationService;
import com.google.api.client.http.ByteArrayContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport;

/**
 * Transport handler to send test and purge requests to Akamai and handle
 * responses. The handler sets up basic authentication with the user/pass from
 * the replication agent's transport config and sends a GET request as a test
 * and POST as purge request. A valid test response is 200 while a valid purge
 * response is 201.
 * 
 * The transport handler is triggered by setting your replication agent's
 * transport URL's protocol to "akamai://".
 *
 * The transport handler builds the POST request body in accordance with
 * Akamai's Fast Purge REST API {@link https://developer.akamai.com/api/core_features/fast_purge/v3.html}
 * using the replication agent properties. 
 */
@Component(service = TransportHandler.class, immediate = true)
public class AkamaiTransportHandler implements TransportHandler {

    /**The Solr Server Configuration Service.*/
    @Reference
    MyProjectConfigurationService myProjectConfigurationService;

    @Reference
    BaseConfigurationService baseConfigurationService;

    /**Logger Instantiation for Akamai Transport Handler*/
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AkamaiTransportHandler.class);

    /** Protocol for replication agent transport URI that triggers this transport handler. */
    private static final String AKAMAI_PROTOCOL = "akamai://";

    /**Config Pid for Akamai Flush*/
    private static final String AKAMAI_FLUSH_CONFIG_PID = "com.myproject.bundle.core.configuration.AkamaiFlushConfiguration";

    /** Replication agent type property name. Valid values are "arl" and "cpcode". */
    private static final String PROPERTY_AKAMAI_TYPE = "type";

    /** Replication agent multifield CP Code property name.*/
    private static final String PROPERTY_AKAMAI_CP_CODES = "4321xxx";

    /** Replication agent domain property name. Valid values are "staging" and "production". */
    private static final String PROPERTY_AKAMAI_DOMAIN = "domain";

    /** Replication agent action property name. Valid values are "remove" and "invalidate". */
    private static final String PROPERTY_AKAMAI_ACTION = "action";

    /** Replication agent default type value */
    private static final String PROPERTY_AKAMAI_TYPE_DEFAULT = "url";

    /** Replication agent default domain value */
    private static final String PROPERTY_AKAMAI_DOMAIN_DEFAULT = "production";

    /** Replication agent default action value */
    private static final String PROPERTY_AKAMAI_ACTION_DEFAULT = "invalidate";

    /**Transport URI*/
    private static final String TRANSPORT_URI = "transportUri";

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean canHandle(AgentConfig config) {
        final String transportURI = config.getTransportURI();

        return (transportURI != null) && (transportURI.toLowerCase().startsWith(AKAMAI_PROTOCOL));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public ReplicationResult deliver(TransportContext ctx, ReplicationTransaction tx)
            throws ReplicationException {

        final ReplicationActionType replicationType = tx.getAction().getType();

        if (replicationType == ReplicationActionType.TEST) {
            return ReplicationResult.OK;
        } else if (replicationType == ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE ||
                replicationType == ReplicationActionType.DEACTIVATE ||
                replicationType == ReplicationActionType.DELETE) {
            LOGGER.info("Replication  Type in Akamai Handler: {}", replicationType);
            String resourcePath = tx.getAction().getPath();
            if (StringUtils.startsWith(resourcePath, myProjectConfigurationService.getContentpath()) 
                || StringUtils.startsWith(resourcePath, myProjectConfigurationService.getAssetpath())) {
// checking for my project specific root page and root dam path.
                LOGGER.info("Calling activate in Akamai for path: {}", resourcePath);
                try {
                    return doActivate(ctx, tx);
                } catch (RequestSigningException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Signing ceremony unsuccessful....");
                    throw new ReplicationException("Signing ceremony unsuccessful: {}", e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("IO Exception in deliver \n");
                    throw new ReplicationException("IO Exception in deliver: {}", e);
                }
            }
            return ReplicationResult.OK;
        } else {
            throw new ReplicationException("Replication action type " + replicationType + " not supported.");
        }
    }

    private String getTransportURI(TransportContext ctx) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info("Entering getTransportURI method.");
        final ValueMap properties = ctx.getConfig().getProperties();
        final String AKAMAI_HOST = baseConfigurationService.getPropValueFromConfiguration(AKAMAI_FLUSH_CONFIG_PID, "akamaiHost");
        final String domain = PropertiesUtil.toString(properties.get(PROPERTY_AKAMAI_DOMAIN), PROPERTY_AKAMAI_DOMAIN_DEFAULT);
        final String action = PropertiesUtil.toString(properties.get(PROPERTY_AKAMAI_ACTION), PROPERTY_AKAMAI_ACTION_DEFAULT);
        final String type = PropertiesUtil.toString(properties.get(PROPERTY_AKAMAI_TYPE), PROPERTY_AKAMAI_TYPE_DEFAULT);
        String defaultTransportUri = MyConstants.HTTPS + AKAMAI_HOST + "/ccu/v3/"
                                    + action + MyConstants.BACK_SLASH + type + MyConstants.BACK_SLASH + domain;
        String transporturi = PropertiesUtil.toString(properties.get(TRANSPORT_URI), defaultTransportUri);

        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(transporturi)) {
            return defaultTransportUri;
        }
        if (transporturi.startsWith(AKAMAI_PROTOCOL)) {
            transporturi = transporturi.replace(AKAMAI_PROTOCOL, MyConstants.HTTPS);
        }
        transporturi =  transporturi + "/ccu/v3/"
                + action + MyConstants.BACK_SLASH + type + MyConstants.BACK_SLASH + domain;
        LOGGER.info("Exiting getTransportURI method of Akamai Transport Handler : {}", transporturi);
        return transporturi;
    }

    /**
     * Send purge request to Akamai via a POST request
     *
     * Akamai will respond with a 201 HTTP status code if the purge request was
     * successfully submitted.
     *
     * @param ctx Transport Context
     * @param tx Replication Transaction
     * @return ReplicationResult OK if 201 response from Akamai
     * @throws ReplicationException
     * @throws RequestSigningException 
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws JSONException 
     */
    private ReplicationResult doActivate(TransportContext ctx, ReplicationTransaction tx)
            throws ReplicationException, RequestSigningException, IOException {
        LOGGER.info("Inside doActivate of Akamai");
        final String AKAMAI_ACCESS_TOKEN = baseConfigurationService.getPropValueFromConfiguration(AKAMAI_FLUSH_CONFIG_PID, "akamaiAccessToken");
        final String AKAMAI_CLIENT_TOKEN = baseConfigurationService.getPropValueFromConfiguration(AKAMAI_FLUSH_CONFIG_PID, "akamaiClientToken");
        final String AKAMAI_CLIENT_SECRET = baseConfigurationService.getPropValueFromConfiguration(AKAMAI_FLUSH_CONFIG_PID, "akamaiClientSecret");
        final String AKAMAI_HOST = baseConfigurationService.getPropValueFromConfiguration(AKAMAI_FLUSH_CONFIG_PID, "akamaiHost");

        ClientCredential clientCredential = ClientCredential.builder().accessToken(AKAMAI_ACCESS_TOKEN).
                clientToken(AKAMAI_CLIENT_TOKEN).clientSecret(AKAMAI_CLIENT_SECRET).host(AKAMAI_HOST).build();


        HttpTransport httpTransport = new ApacheHttpTransport();
        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory();

        JSONObject jsonObject = createPostBody(ctx, tx);


        URI uri = URI.create(getTransportURI(ctx));

        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory.buildPostRequest(new GenericUrl(uri), ByteArrayContent.fromString("application/json", jsonObject.toString()));
        final HttpResponse response = sendRequest(request, ctx, clientCredential);


        if (response != null) {
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
            LOGGER.info("Response code recieved: {}", statusCode);
            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_CREATED) {
                return ReplicationResult.OK;
            }
        }
        return new ReplicationResult(false, 0, "Replication failed");
    }

    /**
     * Build preemptive basic authentication headers and send request.
     *
     * @param request The request to send to Akamai
     * @param ctx The TransportContext containing the username and password
     * @return JSONObject The HTTP response from Akamai
     * @throws ReplicationException if a request could not be sent
     * @throws RequestSigningException 
     */
    private HttpResponse sendRequest(final HttpRequest request, final TransportContext ctx,
            ClientCredential clientCredential)
            throws ReplicationException, RequestSigningException {

        LOGGER.info("Inside Send Request method of Akamai");
        final String auth = ctx.getConfig().getTransportUser() + ":" + ctx.getConfig().getTransportPassword();
        final String encodedAuth = Base64.encode(auth);

         HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
         httpHeaders.setAuthorization("Basic " + encodedAuth);
         httpHeaders.setContentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType());

         request.setHeaders(httpHeaders);

         GoogleHttpClientEdgeGridRequestSigner requestSigner = new GoogleHttpClientEdgeGridRequestSigner(clientCredential);
         requestSigner.sign(request);

         HttpResponse response;

         try {
             response = request.execute();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             LOGGER.error("IO Exception in sendRequest");
             throw new ReplicationException("Could not send replication request.", e);
         }
         LOGGER.info("Sucessfully executed Send Request for Akamai");
         return response;
    }

    /**
     * Build the Akamai purge request body based on the replication agent
     * settings and append it to the POST request.
     *
     * @param request The HTTP POST request to append the request body
     * @param ctx TransportContext
     * @param tx ReplicationTransaction
     * @throws ReplicationException if errors building the request body 
     */
    private JSONObject createPostBody(final TransportContext ctx,
            final ReplicationTransaction tx) throws ReplicationException {
        final ValueMap properties = ctx.getConfig().getProperties();
        final String type = PropertiesUtil.toString(properties.get(PROPERTY_AKAMAI_TYPE), PROPERTY_AKAMAI_TYPE_DEFAULT);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray purgeObjects = null;

        if (type.equals(PROPERTY_AKAMAI_TYPE_DEFAULT)) {
            try {
                String content = IOUtils.toString(tx.getContent().getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset());

                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(content)) {
                    LOGGER.info("Content of Akamai is:\n {}", content);
                    purgeObjects = new JSONArray(content);
                }
            } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                throw new ReplicationException("Could not retrieve content from content builder", e);
            }
        }
        if (null != purgeObjects && purgeObjects.length() > 0) {
            try {
                json.put("objects", purgeObjects);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                throw new ReplicationException("Could not build purge request content", e);
            }
        } else {
            throw new ReplicationException("No CP codes or pages to purge");
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

Also you would need following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.akamai.edgegrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>edgegrid-signer-google-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.akamai.edgegrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>edgegrid-signer-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

For my case, the bundle did not resolve and I had to add below dependencies to resolve it. It might differ in your case though:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opencensus</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencensus-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.24.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opencensus</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencensus-contrib-http-util</artifactId>
        <version>0.24.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-context</artifactId>
        <version>1.24.0</version>
    </dependency>
 <Import-Package>
        javax.annotation;version=0.0.0,
 </Import-Package>
```

For the line : "IOUtils.toString(tx.getContent().getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset());", it internally calls your custom content builder (you can refer the article link I provided earlier). However, you can directly make you content objects in transport handler itself as the transport handler is creating it's own request anyways. However, if you need the session you need to implement the ContentBuilder since TransportHandler implementations do not provide that leverage.

Thanks,
Shubham

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is to write some code that makes an HTTP request to the fast purge endpoint.

Here is some an example:

```
import com.akamai.edgegrid.auth.*;
//other imports

public void callAkamaiFastPurgeForUrls(Set<String> urlsToPurge) throws URISyntaxException, IOException, RequestSigningException {
    if(!urlsToPurge.isEmpty()) {
        int status;
        String json = getPurgeJson(urlsToPurge);
        HttpRequest signedRequest = getHttpRequest(json, compProperty);
        HttpResponse response = signedRequest.execute();

        status = response.getStatusCode();

        if (status == 201) {
            //handle success responses as you see fit
        } else {
            //handle non-success responses as you see fit
        }
    }
}

private static String getPurgeJson(Set<String> pathsToPurge) {
    //your code to turn the list of urls into JSON in this format:
    //{"objects":["https://www.yourdomain.com/page1.html","https://www.yourdomain.com/page2.html"]}

    return //JSON string such as the example above
}


private HttpRequest getHttpRequest(String json, Dictionary<String, Object> dispatcherAndAkamaiServletProperties) throws URISyntaxException, IOException, RequestSigningException {
    String hostName = yourCodeToFetchConfigValues("hostname");
    String accessToken = yourCodeToFetchConfigValues("accesstoken");
    String clientToken = yourCodeToFetchConfigValues("clienttoken");
    String clientSecret = yourCodeToFetchConfigValues("clientsecret");
    String apiUrl = yourCodeToFetchConfigValues("apiurl");
    String proxyServer = yourCodeToFetchConfigValues("proxyhostakamai");
    int proxyPort = yourCodeToFetchConfigValues("proxyport");

    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport.Builder()
            .setProxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyServer, proxyPort))).build();

    HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory();

    URI uri = new URI(HTTPS, hostName, apiUrl, null, null);
    HttpContent body = new ByteArrayContent("application/json", json.getBytes());
    HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildPostRequest(new GenericUrl(uri), body);
    HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
    headers.set("Host", hostName);
    ClientCredential credential = new DefaultCredential(clientToken, accessToken, clientSecret);
    RequestSigner signer = new EdgeGridV1Signer(Collections.emptyList(), 1024 * 2);

    return signer.sign(request, credential);
}
```

In addition you will likely need to update your truststore to include the certificates of the Akamai endpoints you are calling so that the SSL communication can happen.